# Passing unique_ptr to function object

Tags: c++, c++11

Having problems getting the below to compile. I create a function object and try and pass a unique pointer, but the compiler complains saying I am trying to access private data in unique_ptr. This occurs in msvc 2012 v110.

```
class Work
{
};

class A 
{
public:

    void doWork(Work w)
    {
        std::cout << " - - ";
        return;
    }

    void doWork2(std::unique_ptr<Work> w)
    {
        std::cout << " - - ";
        return;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::unique_ptr<Work> w2 = std::unique_ptr<Work>(new Work());

    Work w;
    auto func = std::bind(&A::doWork, a, std::placeholders::_1);
    auto func2 = std::bind(&A::doWork2, a, std::placeholders::_1);
    func(w);
    func2(std::move(w2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code compiles fine under MinGW. Have you included the <memory> header file?

Comment: Since std::unique_ptr<T> are non-copyable, maybe MSVS10 is having a hard time figuring whether or not that call should be a direct initialization or you're trying to use a private *std::unique_ptr<T>( const unique_ptr<T> )* ctor. You should may try the brace-init list instead, so you simply have *std::unique_ptr<Work> w2{ new Work {} };*

Comment: compiled fine on gcc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in VC. See also [this bug report on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/814028).

It seems that VC passes placeholder arguments as lvalue references instead of using perfect forwarding.

The example compiles fine on gcc ([live sample on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f81e8da824562c5)).

As a workaround, you could use a lambda instead of `std::bind`:

```
auto func2 = [&a](std::unique_ptr<Work> w) { a.doWork2(std::move(w)); };
```